# How can I use Amazon Web Services policy statement in my Java application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, spring-cloud

I want to send *Amazon SNS Messages* to *Amazon SQS Queues* from the backend Java application. According to **SNS Developer Guide** (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-dg.pdf), in the section **"Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues"**, under the topic - **"Step 2. Give permission to the Amazon SNS topic to send messages to the Amazon SQS queue"**, it is written as,

> If you wanted to create the policy document yourself, you would create
>   a policy like the following. The policy allows MyTopic to send
>   messages to MyQueue.

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
  {
    "Sid":"MySQSPolicy001",
    "Effect":"Allow",
    "Principal":"*",
    "Action":"sqs:SendMessage",
    "Resource":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
    "Condition":{
                  "ArnEquals":{
                     "aws:SourceArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:MyTopic"
                   }
              }
         }
    ]
}
```

My doubt is how to use this policy document(.json file if I am not wrong) in my java application and where to use it exactly? Because I must set a policy on the queue that allows the Amazon SNS topic to perform the sqs:SendMessage action.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do it in a Java application.

Go to AWS console, select [IAM service](http://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/), choose a user (or create one) and then, under Permissions, you attach Policies.

This is how it looks like:

[image: AWS IAM Policy screenshot]

Policies (the JSON documents) can be chosen from a list, generated using a wizard or entered manually (that's what you want).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will follow it. :+1

Comment: Forgive me for asking you another question here. I have followed instructions for **"Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues"** as it was in SNS-guide. Also I have separately created _crud_ for both SQS & SNS individually. And finally to send notifn to Android app, I have used "SNSMobilePush.java". Now if I run this file in my java application, push Notifn works. Now how to combine these pieces together?
"JavaBackendApp->SNS->SQS->Android APP". Please guide me.

Comment: @Chandz: So you need your JavaBackendApp do to the same thing as SNSMobilePush.java? Why don't copy source code of `demoAndroidAppNotification ` (and other functions) to your JavaBackendApp?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My JavaBackEndApp will use SNSMobilePush.java. When I run this file, it uses demoAndroidAppNotification to send notification to the Android phone. On the other side,I have configured "Sending Amazon SNS Messages to Amazon SQS Queues" using SNS-guide. Now i have to integrate these two pieces. i.e., demoAndroidAppNotification() should send notifn message to SQS and then SQS should send that notifn message to Android app (instead of sending notifn directly to Android phone from demoAndroidAppNotification). How can I achieve it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have experience with these services nor with mobile notifications. But from reading some docs I think there is no reason to use SQS for Android push notification - SNS just sends it directly, no need to queue it with SQS. SQS is queue, it doesn't actively send anything itself. Or do you want to poll notifications in your app?

Comment: If you want to store the notification to SQS, then you should configure SNS:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html#SendMessageToSQS.subscribe Appliction code stays the same, it's SNS that decides where to send what topic, app code just sends the topic.

Comment: There is how to subscribe various end points (mobile push notifications, SQS, ...) to a SNS endpoint: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me. I will check these links. I am sending only 1 notification in morning and 1 notification in the evening. So as you said I think there is no necessity of SQS between SNS and Android app. Thank you very much. :+1

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Java example for creating an SNS topic and SQS queue, subscribing the SQS queue to the SNS topic, giving SNS the permission to send messages to the queue, sending a message to SNS, and reading it from the queue.

```
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Condition;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Policy;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Principal;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Resource;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Statement;
import com.amazonaws.auth.policy.actions.SQSActions;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.RegionUtils;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.CreateQueueRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SetQueueAttributesRequest;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CreateSnsAndSqs {
    private static final String SNS_TOPIC = "my-sns-topic";
    private static final String SQS_NAME = "my-sqs-queue";

    public static void main(String... argv) {
        String regionName = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION")).orElse("us-east-1");
        Region region = RegionUtils.getRegion(regionName);
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        // AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain credentialsChain = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
        AmazonSNS sns = region.createClient(AmazonSNSClient.class, credentialsChain, clientConfiguration);
        AmazonSQS sqs = region.createClient(AmazonSQSClient.class, credentialsChain, clientConfiguration);
        String sqsUrl = sqs.createQueue(new CreateQueueRequest(SQS_NAME)).getQueueUrl();
        String snsTopicArn = sns.createTopic(SNS_TOPIC).getTopicArn();
        String sqsArn = sqs.getQueueAttributes(sqsUrl, Arrays.asList("QueueArn")).getAttributes().get("QueueArn");
        String sqsSubscriptionArn = sns.subscribe(snsTopicArn, "sqs", sqsArn).getSubscriptionArn();
        Policy allowSnsToPostToSqsPolicy = new Policy("allow sns " + snsTopicArn + " to send to queue", Arrays.asList(
                new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
                        .withPrincipals(Principal.All)
                        .withActions(SQSActions.SendMessage)
                        .withResources(new Resource(sqsArn))
                        .withConditions(new Condition().withType("ArnEquals").withConditionKey("aws:SourceArn").withValues(snsTopicArn))
        ));
        sqs.setQueueAttributes(new SetQueueAttributesRequest().withQueueUrl(sqsUrl).addAttributesEntry("Policy", allowSnsToPostToSqsPolicy.toJson()));
        String sqsSubscriptionArn = sns.subscribe(snsTopicArn, "sqs", sqsArn).getSubscriptionArn();
        sns.publish(snsTopicArn, "Hello world");
        ReceiveMessageResult receiveResp = sqs.receiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest(sqsUrl).withWaitTimeSeconds(10));
        for (Message message: receiveResp.getMessages()) {
            System.out.println("Received message " + message.getBody());
            sqs.deleteMessage(sqsUrl, message.getReceiptHandle());
        }
        System.out.println("Deleting");
        sns.deleteTopic(snsTopicArn);
        sqs.deleteQueue(sqsUrl);
    }
}
```

It prints the message to the console like this:

```
Received message {
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "add8d56a-19e6-5806-9424-9a2a796f8f94",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:my-sns-topic",
  "Message" : "Hello world",
  "Timestamp" : "2016-02-19T00:14:01.973Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "XXXaLONGSIGNATUREXXX",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-bb750dd426d95ee9390147a5624348ee.pem",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:my-sns-topic:5e4d08a2-bcdb-4943-afef-5b7b02e30d5a"
}
Deleting
```

Comment: The OP wants to know how to set AWS SNS subscription policy in Java, not how to send message to SNS and so on, it's off-topic I think